# Добавление содержимого файла в начало другого файла

Tags: java

Не получается объединить файлы. Нужно чтобы в первый файл сначала записалось содержимое второго файла, а затем содержимое первого.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String file1 = reader.readLine();
String file2 = reader.readLine();
reader.close();
FileInputStream inputStream1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
int data = 0;
while (inputStream1.available() > 0) {
    data = inputStream1.read();
}
FileInputStream inputStream2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file1);
while (inputStream2.available() > 0) {
    int d = inputStream2.read();
    outputStream.write(d);
}
while (inputStream1.available() > 0) {
    outputStream.write(data);
}
inputStream1.close();
inputStream2.close();
outputStream.close();
```

В первом файле было содержимое: *this is file1*
Во втором: *this is file2*
В итоге программа вывела: *this is file2*

В чём ошибка и как это реализовать?

Comment: потому что как минимум надо поток открыть на добавление `new FileOutputStream(file1, true)`.... изначально всё стерев из файла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно считать содержимое первого файла, после чего записать в него содержимое второго файла и следом сохранённое содержимое первого файла:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String fileName1 = scanner.nextLine();
String fileName2 = scanner.nextLine();
Path path1 = Paths.get(fileName1);
Path path2 = Paths.get(fileName2);
try
{
    byte[] bytes1 = Files.readAllBytes(path1);
    Files.copy(path2, path1, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    Files.write(path1, bytes1, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сам учусь на JavaRush. Ваш код не принимает. Свой переделал и валидатор принял! Но работает все так же. (

Comment: @diz.dostuk почему не принимает? Это ж даже не Java 8 (мало ли - вдруг они на Java 7 сидят). Вы у себя локально тестировали код?

Comment: Да, ваш код полностью рабочий!